# How to convert a database file (.sql) to a .mdf file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, mdf

I have a database that was given to me, but is in a file format (.sql). I want to open it in my SQL Server, but I don't know how, because it says i need a .mdf file?

Can someone help?

Answer (score 4):

Open up the .sql file - if it contains SQL code in plain text, you have most likely received the database as a create script. Run it in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

A .sql file is (usually) just a series of SQL commands that you execute on the SQL server using your preferred GUI or CLI. Try opening it in Notepad to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the data base.
2. Right click displays drop down menu.
3. Select execute SQL file.
4. Search for your .SQL file
5. Click on start button
6. Click close.
7. Press F5.

Answer (score -1):

.Sql file is just a random file holding some SQL queries. While .mdf and .ldf are Microsoft SQL Server Database files which hold an entire database.

Run your file in SQL Server Management Studio.